# Outgoing connections from Tomcat behind AJP connector with HTTP Apache

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ajp

I have a Spring application in a Tomcat using the AJP connector with Apache httpd so that I can access directly the application through: `https://example.com` instead of `https://example.com:9700`.

The Spring application uses Spnego for kerberos communications.

Does the outgoing call pass through the HTTP Apache Server or will Tomcat handle it itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outgoing connections have nothing to do with incoming ones, so the answer is no.

Unless you or your network happens to (configure or) force you to go through a proxy, the outgoing connection is directly between Tomcat and your target.

Why would there be a connection between "incoming through AJP" and "outgoing through http" (or through any protocol) anyway? AJP is just good for *forwarding* http, not as a generic VPN-like proxy.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I wanted confirmation. It wasn't CLEARLY specified on internet other than "inbound request". My Tomcat will then communicate directly using Kerberos and therefore I need to put my certificates in Keystores (TrustStore and KeyStore) so that it correctly works